# Learning SQL: UNION or JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

Forgive me if this seems like common sense as I am still learning how to split my data between multiple tables.

Basically, I have two:

- **`general`** with the fields `userID,owner,server,name`
- **`count`** with the fields `userID,posts,topics`

I wish to fetch the data from them and cannot decide how I should do it: in a UNION:

```
SELECT `userID`, `owner`, `server`, `name`
FROM `english`.`general` 
WHERE `userID` = 54 LIMIT 1 
UNION
SELECT `posts`, `topics` 
FROM `english`.`count` 
WHERE `userID` = 54 LIMIT 1
```

Or a JOIN:

```
SELECT `general`.`userID`, `general`.`owner`, `general`.`server`, 
       `general`.`name`, `count`.`posts`, `count`.`topics` 
FROM `english`.`general` 
JOIN `english`.`count` ON 
     `general`.`userID`=`count`.`userID` AND `general`.`userID`=54 
LIMIT 1
```

Which do you think would be the more efficient way and why? Or perhaps both are too messy to begin with?

Comment: Does the union example actually work??? A union typically requires the same number of fields and data types from each select. You should read up on union here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html. In any case, I suspect you want to go with a join.

Comment: Little pro-tip for you here. If your question is just about a SQL query then there's no need to include the surrounding PHP because that's irrelevant to the question and makes the SQL hard to read. Just post your SQL. Cheers.

Comment: Heh thanks, haven't thought about it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about efficiency, but about how they work.

`UNION` just unions 2 different *independent* queries. So you get 2 result sets one after another.

`JOIN` appends each row from one result set to each row from another result set. So in total result set you have "long" rows (in terms of amount of columns)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I always had trouble telling the difference between the two. :)

Comment: JOIN doesn't just append data; it matches some rows in the first set to some rows in the other set - depending on whether you use inner join, outer join, etc.

Comment: @Bryan: well, I've explained the general mechanism. `UNION` also doesn't just unions 2 result sets, does it? I've made a general explanation, and depending on specific case OP could read documentation or ask another question

Comment: *those who sacrifice correctness for efficency will lose both*

Comment: The comment was intended to support your claim about *how they work*.

Comment: @wildplasser: oh, it is too difficult for me to translate it properly :-S sorry

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness as I don't think it's mentioned elsewhere: often UNION ALL is what's intended when people use UNION.

UNION will remove duplicates (so relatively expensive because it requires a sort). This remove duplicates in the final result (so it doesn't matter if there's a duplicate in a single query or the same data from individual SELECTs). UNION is a set operation.

UNION ALL just sticks the results together: no sorting, no duplicate removal. This is going to be quicker (or at least no worse) than UNION.

If you know the individual queries won't return duplicate results use UNION ALL. (In fact often best to assume UNION ALL and think about UNION if you need that behaviour; using SELECT DISTINCT with UNION is redundant).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a JOIN.  Joining is used to creating a single set which is a combination of related data.  Your union example doesn't make sense (and probably won't run).  UNION is for linking two result sets with identical columns to create  a set that has the combined rows (it does not 'union' the columns.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch users and  near user posts and topics. you need to write QUERY using JOIN like this:

```
SELECT general.*,count.posts,count.topics FROM general LEFT JOIN count ON general.userID=count.userID
```

Comment: This will fetch me all users' data, not the unique one's, as technically both tables will be filled with `userID=1,2,3...`